# No visualization in Rviz when publishing on (collision_object) topic?

Tags: collision, ros, robotics, moveit

I am trying to add a collision object using another way than

```
planning_scene.addCollisionObjects(std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject>)
```

so I am trying to publish on (collision_object) and (attached_collision_object) topics using

```
ros::Publisher pub_co = nh2.advertise<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject>("collision_object", 10);
ros::Publisher pub_aco = nh2.advertise<moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject>("attached_collision_object", 10);
```

However nothing shows in Rviz, when i echo the topic the msg is shown but nothing in Rviz 
I also tried using moveit_visual_tools method

```
visual_tools_->publishCollisionBlock(------)
```

but also i get nothing !

any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was just simply not listening to the correct planning scene Topic, the strange thing is that the topic name was the .cpp file name (does moveit_visual_tools publish the .cpp as a topic name?) 
After the correct planning scene topic was chosen visualization in Rviz was perfect.